# onActivityResult get position

Tags: android

I have an activity that shows a ListView, the ListView is composed by a TextEdit and a Button.
The button is used to pick the email of a contact and put it in the TextEdit.

The listener of the button is created in my custom array adapter and from this method I'm calling the activity to pick the contact like this:

```
Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI);

((Activity) v.getContext()).startActivityForResult(intent, MainActivity.act_pick_contact_mail);
```

I've created the method onActivityResult in my activity and I can get the email picked by the user, but I don't know from wich position the button was pushed.

This is the code I've written:
Do you know how can I do it ?

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

       //Pick an email
    if(requestCode==MainActivity.act_pick_contact_mail){
        try{
            if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK){    

             Uri uri=data.getData(); 
             Cursor emailCur=getContentResolver().query(uri,null, null, null,null);

             emailCur.moveToFirst();
             String email = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS));

             //Change the first item, but I need to know the real position
             contactos.set(0, new Contacto(email));
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

             emailCur.close();

            }}
             catch(Exception e){
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Email wasn't found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
             e.getCause();
             }        
    } 

}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Solved creating an attribute within the adaper with a getter.

Comment: What kind of adapter are you using?

Comment: I't an ArrayAdapter to display a list of custom objects "Contacto"

public class ContactsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contacto>{ ... }

Comment: I'm thinking that may be I can create a public attribute in my class and update it from the adapter class, but I think this is not a good solution, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options here.

One, save the position in a class attribute of your activity. Then reference it when `onActivityResult` returns.

Two, use the position as your request code. Eg replace `MainActivity.act_pick_contact_mail` with the position. Then in `onActivityResult` assume a request code of >= 0 is valid.

Comment: The option two should work, but I prefer the first one. But how to do it? sorry, i'm new to android and java.

If I create a public attribute in my activity, how can I get the reference of my class from the adapter class? 

with this I think I can get the activity ((Activity) v.getContext())
but how can I update the attribute ?

Comment: Is the adapter class nested within the Activity?

Comment: Nop, the adapter class is in another file

Comment: If you know it'll only be used by the one activity: use (ActivityClassName) getContext() from within the Adapter.  That'll give you the Activity's instance. However, the better choice would be to store the position within the adapter and supply a getter for the activity to grab it during the onActivityResult(). Of course that's assuming your onClick() event is defined within the adapter.

Comment: yes, onClick is in the adapter, ok, I've managed to do it adding an attribute to my adapter class and a getter. Thanks. _________

Just for curiosity, I still don't understand how to get the reference to an attribute of my Main activity within the adapter with (ActivityClassName) getContext(). Imagine my activity is called "Main" and the attribute is "myAttr", How to change its value from the adapter?

Comment: ```((Main)getContext()).setMyAttr(newAttr);```  where inside of ```Main``` there exists ```public void setMyAttr(MyAttrType newAttr){ this.myAttr = newAttr; }``` where ```myAttr``` is of type ```MyAttrType```.